# 70mph in 2nd gear in automatic trans. Honda pilot

Tags: engine, honda, pilot

My boyfriend drove me to dr. Yesterday at 70mph with my Honda Pilot in 2 nd gear. Did he damage my car?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Was it just for a brief period, at that speed in second gear?  Had he selected 2nd by mistake?

Answer (score 3):

Probably not since most modern cars have rev limiters in the ECU.  This prevents over-revving the engine and causing damage.

You may want to consider upgrading your boyfriend, though.

Comment: That's what Suze Orman says about literally every relationship LOL.

Answer (score 1):

If there were any real damage, you would know right away.  Listen carefully for any unusual whirring sounds, hard shifting, etc. during normal usage.

You might consider having the transmission fluid changed at a shop.  Running the transmission at a sustained, high rate could easily overheat and sheer the fluid.  Worn fluid will cause damage to internal metal parts before long.  A servicing costs about $125 for your vehicle and would be well worth the effort.